# Can I add a .php file URL to Blogger?

Tags: php, forms, url, blogger, contact-form

I would like to know if there's a way to add a .php file to a Blogger template using a direct link. I am unsure whether or not I can add it to my form action with a URL as Blogger does not support .php directly.

```
<form method="post" action="CAN_I_USE_A_URL_HERE?.php">

    <input name="Name" placeholder="Name*:"/>

    <input name="E-mail" type="email" placeholder="E-mail*:"/>

    <input name="Phone" type="email" placeholder="Phone:"/>

    <label>Write your message!</label>
    <textarea name="Message"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: You need your own server.

Comment: I've been following this tutorial: http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/ And was planning on self hosting it on Google Drive since it's such a small thing.

Comment: No; if you want server-side code, you need a real server.

Comment: I understand, I don't have a server as this is a test project and I hosted it on Blogger. Nevertheless, is there no possibility of adding a URL to the attribute action? I would not be able to do this: <?php echo $url ?> (being $url the path to the hosted file), because Blogger doesn't support php. It does support it as a script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PChZIr1215g Maybe the problem is Dropbox or Google Drive that don't run the php file. It just downloads it when I use the URL on the action or embedded as an object.

Comment: Exactly.  You need a server that can run PHP code.

Comment: That video is just sending a request to a server that will run PHP code.

Comment: I've managed to make it work with 000webhost using the link on the action attribute. Still got some errors, but got the contact form working. Feel free to submit your answer so I can mark it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger will not run server-side code.

You need to put your PHP code on some server that will run it for you, then make the `<form>` point to that.